# Creating instance of DAO without @inject for modularising Web app

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick

I'm building my test project based on [this demo](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/blob/master/samples/di/app/controllers/Application.scala) :

What I want to do is to be able to use `CatDao` inside of a `function` in an `object`, so, no `@inject` will be available.

What I'm trying to do is to have a modular web. In which every section of the page (sections will be templates) is responsible for loading the data that will be shown to the user.

Is this possible, if so, is this a good practice in Scala Play?

Comment: `@Inject` should [work](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html) for methods as well, am i missing something?

Comment: I can't find where to put it in Scala. This is what I'm trying to inject: @Inject() (var catDao: CatDAO)

Comment: I never tried it before, but according to the docs before the method declaration, i.e this compiles for me - `@Inject() def myFunc(str: String) = 1`

Comment: Maybe is something I'm missing, but how you say that way what you are trying to inject?

Comment: I assume it works the same way as with constructors, in this case you want it to inject a string, value for which you are [binding](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Programmatic-bindings) in a Play Module file.